# how to get value attribute of radio input with cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-testing-library

I have a radio element `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />`

below is my cypress code

`cy.getAllByRole("radio").first().click()`

how do I get the value attribute of the radio element?
something like this

`const radioValue = cy.getAllByRole("radio").first().getValue() //"male"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
cy.getAllByRole('radio')
  .first()
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    cy.log(val) //logs male
  })
```

Answer (score 6):

To be unambiguous, the `value="male"` is an ***attribute*** so you would use

```js
cy.getAllByRole('radio')
  .first()
  .invoke('attr', 'value')
  .should('eq', 'male')           // assert it
  .then(value => cy.log(value))   // or pass it down the chain
```

The command `.invoke('val')` is getting the ***property***, and only works for the ***selected*** radio option, which by default is the first option.

If you tried it on the second option, it would fail.

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
```

```js
cy.getAllByRole('radio')
  .eq(1)                     // take the second
  .invoke('attr', 'value')
  .should('eq', 'female')    // ✅ passes!

cy.getAllByRole('radio')
  .eq(1)                     
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'female')    // ❌ fails!

cy.getAllByRole('radio')
  .eq(1)                     
  .click()                  // change the selected item

cy.getAllByRole('radio')
  .eq(1)          
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'female')    // ✅ now it passes
```

In summary, you can check ***attributes*** at any time, but checking the ***property*** only works after the click action occurs.